# Django Signals - How to save the instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, thumbnails, django-signals, moviepy

I am using `Django Rest Framework` to upload videos. Now I wanted to add thumbnails to my video files. Whenever a Video object is saved, I wanted to create a thumbnail and set its `thumbnail` field.

My Video model looks like this:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='Videos/',blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/', blank = True)
```

My signal handler looks like this:

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
from posts.models import Video
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from settingsFolderOfProject.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
import os

# when save() of Video is done, create_thumbnail_from_video() is called
@receiver(post_save, sender=Video)
def create_thumbnail_from_video(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # create the clip using moviepy's VideoFileClip class
        clip = VideoFileClip(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, instance.video.name))
        # create the frame at 1st second and set it to instance's thumbnail field
        instance.thumbnail = clip.save_frame(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'Images/thumbnail.jpg'),t='00:00:01') 
        # save the instance 
        instance.save()       # <--- I think this op does not work properly
```

What I have to change? 
The thumbnail file gets created in the folder as expected but Django does not set the `thumbnail` field of my `Video` model instance. The `thumbnail` field of the created `Video` instance is still set to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clip.save_frame() doesn't return anything.
Instead do

```
path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'Images/thumbnail.jpg')
clip.save_frame(path,t='00:00:01') 
instance.thumbnail = path
instance.save()
```

Note: Haven't tested yet. Comment if problem still persists. Thnx...